# Проблема с функцией

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Как сделать, что-бы функция вернула многомерный массив?

$people1 = многомерный, массив полученный после запроса к БД и пройденный через функцию mysql_fetch_assoc()

```
function validZero($people1){
foreach ($people1 as $delete)

{
 $delete['children1'] != 0 ? $children1 = 1 : $children1 = 0;
 $delete['children2'] != 0 ? $children2 = 1 : $children2 = 0;
 $delete['children3'] != 0 ? $children3 = 1 : $children3 = 0;
 $delete['children4'] != 0 ? $children4 = 1 : $children4 = 0;

}
   return array($children1, $children2, $children3, $children4);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validZero($people1){
$mass = array();

  foreach ($people1 as $delete){
    $delete['children1'] != 0 ? $children1 = 1 : $children1 = 0;
    $delete['children2'] != 0 ? $children2 = 1 : $children2 = 0;
    $delete['children3'] != 0 ? $children3 = 1 : $children3 = 0;
    $delete['children4'] != 0 ? $children4 = 1 : $children4 = 0;
    $mass[] = array($children1, $children2, $children3, $children4);
  }
return $mass;
}
```

Не?

Comment: спасибо, в чем моя ошибка заключалась?

Comment: Ну, вы проверьте сначала.

Comment: проверил работает

Comment: Я просто добавил [] после массива. Это операция PUSH, у вас массив затирается на каждом шаге

Answer (score 2):

Я-бы делал присвоение, всё-таки, так:

```
$children1 = $delete['children1'] != 0 ? 1 : 0;
```

А саму функцию так ( код частично от [@knes](/users/2825/knes) ):

```
function validZero( $people ){
  $res = array();

  foreach ( $people as $delete ){
    $res[] = array(
      $delete['children1'] != 0 ? 1 : 0,
      $delete['children2'] != 0 ? 1 : 0,
      $delete['children3'] != 0 ? 1 : 0,
      $delete['children4'] != 0 ? 1 : 0
    );
  }

  return $res;
}
```